# Not turtlebot added to the world gazebo environment

Tags: ros2

I am trying to roslaunch turtlebot3_world.launch in ros2 noetic. However, after launhcing just the world is opend in gazebo and i can not see the robot. how can I solve the problem.

thanks in advance,

here is the launch file.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="-2.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="-0.5"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</launch>
```